# PowerPivot for Excel 2010 not installing on Office 2010 Home And Business

Tags: microsoft-office, powerpivot

I'm trying to install Microsoft PowerPivot on a machine with a full Office 2010 Home and Student installation, and I'm not able to get the installation to work properly.  The COM library will not register at startup.

I installed separately on a computer with Microsoft Office Professional Plus 2010, and it worked first try.

Is this a license/edition issue with Home and Student?  I know 2013 was like that, but I cant find any technical documentation stating otherwise.

Comment: Can you please tell us the exact problem that you have. One of the possible causes is the prerequisites not being there, mentioned in the answer by Karan.

Answer (score 0):

As [this page](http://office.microsoft.com/sites/preview/en-us/excel/download-powerpivot-HA101959985.aspx) states, you need to keep all the following in mind:

**Prerequisites**

- [.NET Framework 4.0](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=17851).
- [Visual Studio 2010 Tools for Office Runtime](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=35594).
- If applicable, [Platform Update for Windows Server 2008 and Windows Vista](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/971644).

**Important Notes**

- If you choose a custom installation of Microsoft Office 2010, you must install both **Excel 2010** and **Office Shared Tools**. Otherwise, you will not be able to use PowerPivot for Excel.
- If you are using the 32-bit version of Excel 2010, you must use the 32-bit version of PowerPivot. If you are using the 64-bit version of Excel 2010, you must use the 64-bit version of PowerPivot. The versions are *not* interchangeable.

Comment: Karan, that is corrrect.  I do have all the prerequisites on both systems I tried.  However I think the problem is with the edition of Office 2010.

I was looking for an answer if PowerPivot was never designed to work with Office 2010 Home and Businesss.

Comment: I could find no mention of any version restriction anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem and have tried all the suggestions i could find online.
It must be that you need a `business user license` as I see it attempts to load as a business user "first load" (after office features tinkered with and so a fresh start up of the applications) then realizes it it a non commercial user set up and thereafter ignores the add-in on start up/reload.

Typical of Microsoft, head in the box not realizing/thinking/anticipating basic instructions should include information about what packages their wonderful? tools work with would save users a lot of valuable hours....and might have stopped me buying 4 Mac Books